# Deleting and Persisting different entities using 1 EntityManager in Doctrine/Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, sonata-admin, sonata

If I have one call to `->remove()` or `->persist()` and then a `->flush()` this works fine, however, I would like $entity1 to be deleted ($em->remove()) and $entity2 to be persisted.

Here's the code. Note that $entity1 and $entity2 are two separate entities/classes:

```
$em->persist($entity1);
$em->flush();
$em->detach($entity1); // detaching because $entity2 is a different class of Entities.
$em->remove($entity2);
$em->flush();
```

I also tried passing in `@doctrine` as a param to the constructor (EntityRegistry) with the following with no luck:

```
$em = $this->mr->getManagerForClass(get_class($entity1));
$em->persist($entity1);
$em->flush();

$em2 = $this->mr->getManagerForClass(get_class($entity2));
em2->remove($entity2);
$em2->flush();
```

The issue is, the new $entity1 is created, but $entity2 is not removed. The logs show DELETE FROM * and INSERT INTO * queries..

In particular I am using Sonata, not standalone Doctrine or Symfony.

Comment: note: $entity1 and $entity2 have no association to each other. They are both OneToOne from a common class however, and I would like to keep this common object in the DB as-is. I just want these entites to change.

Comment: Is your $entity2 object fetched and still stay in Entity Manager?

Comment: Ca you post the mapping of the three entities?

Comment: @Tuannguyen yes, I suppose so, how do I "detach"?